# How can I use OAuth2/OpenID in FastAPI using an external authentication server (Keycloak)?

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, keycloak, fastapi, openid

I am building an application in [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/)  where all endpoints have to be password protected with 2FA. I am using [Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/) as an authentication server which should support 2FA.

My code looks as follows:

```python
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, HTTPException, Depends, status
from authlib.integrations.httpx_client import AsyncOAuth2Client
from starlette.responses import RedirectResponse
from starlette.config import Config
import requests, json

app = FastAPI()

config = Config(".env")  # reads values from .env file

app = FastAPI()

client_id = "myclient"
# client_id = config('CLIENT_ID')
client_secret = "<client_secret>"
client_redirect_uri = "http://localhost:8080/authenticate/callback"

client = AsyncOAuth2Client(client_id=client_id, 
                           client_secret=client_secret,
                           redirect_uri=client_redirect_uri,
                           scope='openid',
                           auth_url='http://localhost:8080/keycloak/auth/realms/test_realm/protocol/openid-connect/auth',
                           token_url='http://localhost:8080/keycloak/auth/realms/test_realm/protocol/openid-connect/token',
                           revocation_url='http://localhost:8080/keycloak/auth/realms/test_realm/protocol/openid-connect/logout')

@app.get("/login")
async def login(request: Request):
    redirect_uri = request.url_for('auth_callback')
    redirect_uri = "http://localhost:8080/keycloak/auth/realms/test_realm/protocol/openid-connect/auth"
    auth_url = client.create_authorization_url(redirect_uri)
    # return auth_url
    # print(auth_url)
    # redirect user to auth_url
    return RedirectResponse(auth_url[0])

@app.get("/authenticate")
async def auth(request: Request):
    code = request.query_params.get("code")
    state = request.query_params.get("state")
    session_state = request.query_params.get("session_state")
    # send post request to token endpoint http://localhost:8080/keycloak/auth/realms/test_realm/protocol/openid-connect/token
    url = "http://keycloak:8080/keycloak/auth/realms/test_realm/protocol/openid-connect/token"

    payload=f'grant_type=authorization_code&code={code}&client_id=myclient&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fauthenticate%2Fcallback&client_secret={client_secret}'
    headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }

    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

    token = response.text
    # convert to dict
    token = json.loads(token)


    return token

@app.get("/authenticate/callback")
async def auth_callback(token: dict = Depends(auth)):
    # print token information to the console
    print("TOKEN!!!")
    print(token)
    return {"message": "Check the console for session information."}



# I want to protect this endpoint with OAuth2
@app.get("/")
async def index():
# async def index():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}
```

If the user accesses the `/login` endpoint they will be redirected to the Keycloak server and asked to enter their credentials. Then a redirect to `/authenticate/callback` is made which is dependent on the `/authenticate` endpoint. Here I successfully use the authorization code that the user got from Keycloak to obtain an access token.
As I understand, this access token can be used to validate the user until it expires and then refreshed with the refresh token.
What I do not understand is how this works when it is stored server side. How does the user access another endpoint such as the root (/) and get verified? Is there some information about the session that has to be linked with the access token and verified each time the user makes a request?

I'm looking for a way to make the authorization and then allow the user to keep making requests at different endpoints making sure it is still the same user, until the access token expires. How can I make sure the user keeps being logged in?

I might have misunderstood some things regarding the OAtuh flow, so any suggestions would be appreciated?

For anyone not familiar with Keycloak, the following OpenID endpoint configurations are defined:

```json
issuer  "http://localhost:8080/keycloak/auth/realms/test_realm"
authorization_endpoint  "http://localhost:8080/keycloak/auth/realms/test_realm/protocol/openid-connect/auth"
token_endpoint  "http://localhost:8080/keycloak/auth/realms/test_realm/protocol/openid-connect/token"
token_introspection_endpoint    "http://localhost:8080/keycloak/auth/realms/test_realm/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect"
userinfo_endpoint   "http://localhost:8080/keycloak/auth/realms/test_realm/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo"
end_session_endpoint    "http://localhost:8080/keycloak/auth/realms/test_realm/protocol/openid-connect/logout"
jwks_uri    "http://localhost:8080/keycloak/auth/realms/test_realm/protocol/openid-connect/certs"
check_session_iframe    "http://localhost:8080/keycloak/auth/realms/test_realm/protocol/openid-connect/login-status-iframe.html"
```

Comment: You'll still need some soft of session management; pass a session cookie back to the browser, ensure it's stored securely and verify that cookie on incoming requests.  There's also the option of doing the whole flow in browser e.g using keycloak-js and then the access token is available for requests to the api server later on but there are security issues with this so YMMV depending on security context.